# How do I select all of my rows from an eloquent model where A column or B column equals to 'Mom'?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm working on Laravel framework version 5.6

How do I select all of my rows from an eloquent model where A column or B column equals to 'Mom'?

Sorry if I haven't explained myself very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this
For example,

*Model: App\User*

```
App\User::where('first_name','=','Mom')->orWhere('last_name','=', 'Mom')->get();
```